# PhoneGap Build Certificate doesn't match profile error

Tags: ios, phonegap-build, p12

I am attempting to complete my app build in Phone Gap to create an IPA file for App Store submission. However, I am constantly running into:
"Error:certificate doesn't match profile the default keychain doesn't have an identity matching"
...and I am clueless on how to fix this or what the problem is really indicating. This is my first app build, I created my certificate and mobileprovisioning file in Apple Developers account. I have successfully generated a p12 file from my distribution certificate.
I have been searching the web for days and Phone Gap's forums and even the link of "fix this error here, which takes me to a page that offers no real help, or that which I can make sense of. The information is simply not explicit enough to me to let me know what I need to fix. I've followed the tutorials and examples of certificate generation to a T, but I am stuck with this error time after time.

I simply do not know what the error is stating. I do not know what is the "profile" nor what is meant by "...The default keychain doesn't have an identity matching"

Please can someone let me know what exactly this is telling me so I can begin to know how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

iOS certificates are notoriously difficult. What is most likely happening here is that there is a mismatch between the *type* of certificate (p12) and the provisioning profile - development or distribution.  Meaning, you must use a development cert with a development provisioning profile, and same with distribution.

Steps (start from the beginning to ensure that there's not a mismatch):

- Ensure that XCode and MacOS are updated to the latest version.
- Extract the distribution certificate from Apple Keychain.  Expand the iPhone Developer certificate entry, then select both items - the certificate and the private key together. You can do this by selecting the certificate first, then holding the command key and clicking on the private key. Next, right-click and choose the "export two items" option. You'll be prompted to save the export as a p12 file.
- Back over in Apple Dev site, create a new iOS provisioning profile. Choose "Distribution, App Store" as the type.
- Upload both to PhoneGap Build and rebuild.